# Is there a way to load a new assembly and automatically send it to TestFlight with fastlane?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

We use fastlane to send ipa, screenshots and descriptions. Is it possible to send an assembly to the TestFlight together with the ipa download, but not send it to the review?

Comment: Could you share you Fastfile? Could be that all you need is to set "submit_for_review" in **deliver** params to **false**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pilot` feature of `fastlane`, that will distribute your build to TestFlight testers (internally or externally), but not submit it to App Store Review.

```
gym
pilot
```